# Understanding the process for plotting $x(t)=(1/2)*δ(t+2)$

Tags: signal-processing, dirac-delta

I have stumbled upon an exercise where I have to plot/calculate the output of different variations of input functions in a LTI system similar to the one given as a example below (which is supposed to be there to help...):

$x(t)=(1/2)(δ(t+2))$

which should plot, as per the book, to:

[image]

The problem is, I don't understand the process for getting this output. I'm also not sure if I should be using the Laplace transform for it, somehow.

Any hints are welcome.

Comment: But ... shouldn't it be an infinitely narrow peak, the Dirac delta?

Comment: That's what I thought, too, but it seems to be bounded.

Comment: And why is the pyramid at $t=1$ ? Listen, I would plot it as an infinitely tall, infinitely thin peak at $t=-2$. Why at $t=-2$? Because then the argument of $\delta()$ is zero. Why infinitely tall? Because the Dirac delta is infinitely tall. The factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ doesn't change anything.